# ASP.NET Core 3.1 controller method for handling token request from client application

Tags: asp.net-core

There is a client application that authenticates into our system using Bearer tokens. The application request a token like this (simplified version):

```cs
HttpContent content = new StringContent(String.Format("grant_type=password&username={0}&password={1}", usernameTextBox.Text, passwordTextBox.Password), Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
HttpResponseMessage response;
response = await httpClient.PostAsync(ResourceBaseAddress + "/token", content);
```

This current works in ASP.NET MVC 5 and now we are migrating to ASP.NET Core 3.1. I believe I had all bits of server side in place. My difficulty is in how to  declare a controller method that can properly receive the username and password, without changing the calling application code. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever `ResourceBaseAddress` is would contain your controller. Then your method could have this signature:

```
[HttPost]
public IActionResult Token(string grant_type, string username, string password)
{}
```

Answer (score 1):

As your content-type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, so asp.net core default model binder will read it from http request body and map to the complex type which will have similar property names as in http request form data.

You can check the screenshot below for reference.

[image]